# Android: Neither res/raw files nor assets can be loaded

Tags: android, file, assets

I try to load a .ini file in android, but it doesn't work. Until now I have tried the following two ways:

Load file from res/raw folder:

```
int fileId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", context.getPackageName());
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(fileId)));

// I tried this too:
//context.getResources().openRawResource(fileId)));
```

I first thought that the context might be the problem but the getIdentifier() method returns the correct R.raw id, and at openRawResource() the logcat always shows this:

```
03-17 00:17:41.627: W/ResourceType(28752): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f040000
03-17 00:17:41.627: W/System.err(28752): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000
```

And when I try to load the file from the /assets directory:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(fileName)));
```

...I always get the FileNotFoundException:

```
03-17 00:33:32.006: W/System.err(30447): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file.ini: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I hope someone can help me solving this, I just don't know where to look. I also searched and found similar problems on the internet, but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, now I found the mistake.
The code I posted above was working but immediately after that my program called a method(what it shouldn't do) that caused a FileNotFoundException. Because of this I always looked on the wrong part of the code.
Now I use the method for opening files from the /assets directory and it works like it should.
Nevertheless, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If `fileName` is `file.ini`, then your `getIdentifier()` call will fail, as resource names do not contain file extensions. Use `file` (or, better yet, get rid of `getIdentifier()` altogether and use `R.raw.file`).

With respect to the second approach, your project directory needs to be `assets/`, not `asset/`.

Comment: getIdentifier() returns the correct value from the R.java file(I use the file extension only for the assets variant).

Comment: And thanks for the tip with /assets (I did a typo when posting), but that doesn't seem to be the problem. The app can't find the file although it is mentioned in R.java. Unfortunately using R.raw.file didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file names very carefully:

1) Make sure they are all lowercase and defined as such in your coding
2) Make sure yoru filetypes are right (e.g. an .OTF referenced as a .TTF causes this problem)
3) Make sure your fileroutes are correct. e.g. r.id.whatever

Have fun :)

Comment: The file name ist lowercase and is in the res/raw folder. Even if I skip the getIdentifier method and just use R.raw.file I get the FileNotFoundException as with the /assets approach.